# Adding github database to a Django project

Tags: python, django, database, github, web

```
def HashBrut(request):
    
    sha1hash = request.POST.get('decoder','default')
    time.sleep(4)

    LIST_OF_COMMON_PASSWORDS = str(urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials/10-million-password-list-top-10000.txt').read(), 'utf-8')

    for guess in LIST_OF_COMMON_PASSWORDS.split('\n'):

        hashedGuess = hashlib.sha1(bytes(guess, 'utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if hashedGuess == sha1hash:
            val=hashedGuess
            print("The password is ", str(guess))
            ans=str(guess)
            quit()
      
        elif hashedGuess != sha1hash:
            print("Password guess ",str(guess)," does not match, trying next...")

    print("Password not in database, we'll get them next time.")
    params={'text':val,'text1':ans}
    return render(request,'Hashed.html',params)
```

I am trying to access this"LIST_OF_COMMON_PASSWORDS" from github inside my django project. The python functions works fine in terminal but when i use it inside my views.py file in Django project and try to execute it on the web file, it gives *'A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.'* error. I am new to Django and i don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: A view is supposed to return a response... Your view `HashBrut` does not return anything let alone a response.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Actually i had uploaded just the piece of code that I thought was creating issues. I have updated and uploaded my full python function now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue in your code is you have written this line `quit()` which basically means to close the running python process! To **break** out of a loop one normally uses the **`break`** statement. Next you have potentially **10000** prints if the password is not matching! printing to the console does take some time and printing 10000 times would make your request timeout before the server ever sends a response to the client. Don't print if there is no match, just continue. Plus there is a chance that `ans` or `val` may never be defined that too can cause an error, define it at the start with some value:

```
def HashBrut(request):
    ans, val = None, None
    sha1hash = request.POST.get('decoder','default')
    time.sleep(4)

    LIST_OF_COMMON_PASSWORDS = str(urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials/10-million-password-list-top-10000.txt').read(), 'utf-8')

    for guess in LIST_OF_COMMON_PASSWORDS.split('\n'):

        hashedGuess = hashlib.sha1(bytes(guess, 'utf-8')).hexdigest()
        if hashedGuess == sha1hash:
            val=hashedGuess
            print("The password is ", str(guess))
            ans=str(guess)
            # No `quit()` here! use `break`
            break
        # No print here, takes too much time
    print("Password not in database, we'll get them next time.")
    params={'text':val,'text1':ans}
    return render(request,'Hashed.html',params)
```

Comment: Thank you and it actually worked for me. As you mentioned the server was taking way too long and that was causing the error. Once again thanks a lot for your help. @AbdulAzizBarkat